# String to dictionary, and back again

Tags: c#, .net

I working with a string like this:

```
Norway, true; Sweden, false; England, null; Denmark, false;
```

I'm trying to get that into a `Dictionary<string, bool?>` so I can work with it, remove items, compare against other stuff. When I'm done, I want to convert the dictionary back to a similar string and save it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run into a specific issue? Show us some code.

Comment: Are you having trouble with getting it to a dictionary or from a dictionary? They are not really the same problem...

Comment: `Any ideas?`: yes, a lot. We just expect you to show a minimal effort of trying to solve the problem, and, if needed, post a specific issue you encountered. SO is not a site for "please write the code for me" question. If you need more information, please consult [Faq] and [ask] pages, and http://whathaveyoutried.com.

Comment: Sorry not for providing any code. I was struggling with the split method to properly populate the dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert this to dictionary using the `Split` method and LINQ:

```
var dict = str.Split(';')
    .Select(s => s.Split(','))
    .ToDictionary(
        p => p[0].Trim()
    ,   p => p[1].Trim().Equals("null") ? null : (bool?)(bool.Parse(p[1].Trim()))
    );
```

Converting back is even easier:

```
var res = string.Join("; ", dict.Select(
    p => string.Format(
        "{0}, {1}"
    ,   p.Key
    ,   p.Value.HasValue ? p.Value.ToString().ToLowerCase() : "null"
    )
));
```

Comment: `; "null"` should be `: "null"`

Comment: Also add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` spliting option while spliting string value and `ToLowerCase()` must be `ToLower()`